# Speed of Orbiting Formula

Tags: integration, derivatives, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

Consider a star located at the origin of a coordinate system. A planet orbiting the star
has polar coordinates ($r, θ$) where $r$ is a constant. What is the shape of the orbit? If
$\frac{dθ}{dt} = ω$
where $ω$ is constant, write down an expression for the speed of the planet in terms of $r
$ and $ω$.

I believe the shape of the orbit is a circle since $r$ is constant.

I am unsure about the second part. I first thought that this since this a circle, we can write $ω = \frac{dθ}{dt} = \frac{2\pi}{\frac{2\pi r}{v}} = \frac{v}{r}$, so $v = ωr$.

My other thought was that since $r$ is a constant, and the force of gravity always points towards centre of coordinate system, that it must be a central force. Is this a valid method of solving ?

Comment: It is a circle. To solve $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$ just integrate over $t.$

Comment: @KurtG. This gives me $\theta = \omega t + c$ where $c$ is a constant. I can set $\theta = 0$ at $t=0$ so $c=0$. I have $\theta = \omega t$. What do I do from here ?

Comment: What is the question that remains?

Comment: @KurtG. The question states that $v$ must be in terms of $\omega$ and $r$. How do I do this ? Was my method that I used in my opening question correct ? If not, why not ? Thanks

Comment: If you read OP carefully you may notice that you already expressed $v$ in terms of $\omega$ and $r$. In general: as long as I don't say something is incorrect you may assume this is not the case.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @KurtG. Okay so I was correct then. Thanks for letting me know. Question: did you tell me to integrate the equation to obtain $\theta = \omega t$ to verify that it was a circle and it was in no way relevant to determining the speed $v$?

Comment: No. If I had that in mind I would have clearly said that.

Comment: @KurtG. Okay thanks I understand now. Would a central forces approach work as I stated in the end of my opening post ?

Comment: Strictly speaking the sentence "since r
 is a constant, and the force of gravity always points towards centre of coordinate system, that it must be a central force" is a tautology. If gravity always points towards the centre how else would you call that force?